# Grant users of role the ability to edit users that have specific role

Tags: 6, users

Is there a way to make it so users of role A can edit/create users with role B, but not users of role A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [User protect](http://drupal.org/project/userprotect) module.

Comment: This seems to prevent edits\deletes but doesn't give me control over creation. I should have mentioned I need create functionality too.

Comment: I see you asked this in a separate question (which I have answered. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7585/set-role-of-user-when-youre-not-the-admin/7586#7586 )